# Is it possible to have a activity START_STICKY?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

As I know we can have a Service to `START_STICKY` which it will not be killed ( or will restart if so) when a Activity is killed.

Is it possible to have a `START_STICKY` in a Activity or it is only possible in Services ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a START_STICKY in a Activity

No.

Comment: Why it isn't possible?

Comment: @holpducki: For the simple reason that it does not exist.

Comment: is activity lifecycle orthogonal (not dependent) with service lifecycle ?

Comment: @ransh: For started services, yes. A service that is started will be considered running until something stops it (or the process terminates), and that is not tied to the status of any activity that had started the service. Bound services (`bindService()`) are somewhat more dependent on the activity that bound to them.